# Noob user. No network (wired). Cannot ping router

Tags: internet, network-manager, iptables, wired

Let me start by saying I am pretty new to Linux, so forgive my unavoidable noobness and thank you for readning this.

I am trying to set up a good environment to learn programming and familiarize myself with Linux. I already have a Windows 7 installed on my PC.

I ran into network problems everytime I tried Ubuntu. At first I thought I was something with the VirtualBox I was using, but when I tried booting Ubuntu from a live USB stick I had the exact same issue.

I can't ping the router (192..168.0.1) and the IP tables are empty (when I use the route command). Pinging localhost works fine.

One suggestion I ran into was to try:

`sudo iproute add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0`

but I get

`RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable`

I tried booting Ubuntu on a different PC that ran winXP on the same Network, but had the same issue once again.

I may be missing something really obvious here, so forgive me if that's the case. I hope I can learn something from you answers. Tell me if there is more info that I need to provide to clarify the issue. Thanks in advance.

```
ifconfig
eth0 
Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:f5:6f:e6
inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fef5:6fe6/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1561 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:120 (120.0 B) TX bytes:251910 (251.9 KB)
```

Update:

I manually edited the conection using the GUI. Under IPv4 settings I set the method to Manual. I entered: "Address 192.168.0.22, Netmask 255.255.255.0, Gateway 192.168.0.1". This made the No Network message change to "Connected: Wired connetion 1". Unfortunetly I am still unable to get internet access. When I try to ping the router I get a Host Unreachable message and 100% packet loss.

Comment: My Ubuntu version is 14.04 32 bits. All other windows computers in the network can connect normally without need for manual settings. There is even a laptop which runs Kali Linux and it can connect to the wireless network straight out of the box, without any additional configuration as well.

Comment: you don't have IP set on eth0, ipv6 is default one, how do connect to the network ? wifi ? rj45 ?

Comment: I am attempting to connect via cable, so I guess the answer would be rj45? I am also pretty sure the win computers in the network use ipv4, all the ip addresses on the network are in the usual 192.168.0.xxx format. Not sure if this info helps. Also this is the only computer in the network connecting via cable, all others use wifi.

Comment: what is the result of `ifdown eth0` then `ifup eth0` ?

Comment: ifdown: interface eth0 is not configured.

Comment: I manually edited the conection using the GUI. Under IPv4 settings I set the method to Manual. I entered: "Address 192.168.0.22, Netmask 255.255.255.0, Gateway 192.168.0.1". This made the No Network message change to "Connected: Wired connetion 1". Unfortunetly I am still unable to get internet access. When I try to ping the router I get a Host Unreachable message and 100% packet loss.